# Bounding summations using big-O

Tags: summation, asymptotics

Can somebody help me bound the following sum in terms of Big-O?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\lg\lg n} n^{1-\frac{1}{2^i}}$$

I've figured out that it is $O(n \lg\lg n)$ by

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\lg\lg n} n^{1-\frac{1}{2^i}}&=n\sum_{i=1}^{\lg\lg n} n^{-\frac{1}{2^i}}\\
&\leq n\sum_{i=1}^{\lg\lg n}1\\
&=O(n\lg\lg n)
\end{align}
$$

but that is too loose.

Is it even possible to get a $O(n)$ bound?

Comment: Are you only looking for an upper bound? What if you could also find a lower bound?

Comment: Yes, I am only looking for an upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The last term of $\sum_{i=1}^{\lg\lg n}n^{-1/2^i}$ is at most $n^{-1/2^{\lg\lg n}}=1/2$, and for the rest, the $i$-th term is the square of the $(i+1)$-th. Thus, *this* sum has an upper bound of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-2^k}$, which is finite.